# how to name a object in the list

Tags: r

I tried to add a data.frame into a list. How can I keep the name of the new data in the list `datalist1`.

Here is what I did:

```
test <-  read.csv(paste0(file_dir,"test.CSV"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

datalist2<- c(list(test),datalist1)
```

However the new data `test` did not show up as `test` in `datalist2`. what should I do?

[image]

Comment: How about `datalist2<- c(test=list(test),datalist1)`? But in general we try to avoid appending to a list with `c()` because it can be inefficient if you need to do it a bunch (there are often better, more R-like ways to do the same thing).

Comment: Or if you need to change the names after the list is made `names(datalist2)[1] <-"test"`

Comment: Thanks. It works. By the way, how can I do in a more r-like way?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::lst`

```
 library(dplyr)
 c(lst(test), datalist1)
```